# Swift UIButton Image size distorted in BarButtonItem

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimage, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I want to add an `UIButton` to the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.
I want the `UIButton` to be `24x24px` and scale the Image down.
But the Button got distorted... If I change the `UIImage` to a smaller image everything is fine. -> see pics

What can I do apart from the `scaleAspectFit` ??

```
    let userProfilePic = UIButton()
    userProfilePic.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
    userProfilePic.setImage(UIImage(named: "profile_icon.jpg"), for: .normal)
    userProfilePic.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    userProfilePic.clipsToBounds = true
    userProfilePic.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    userProfilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    userProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = (userProfilePic.frame.size.width) / 2
    userProfilePic.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToSettings), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: userProfilePic)
```

[image]



Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

The is problem appears on `ios 11+` ,  UIBarButtonItem use autolayout on ios 11+ other use frames

```
     let userProfilePic = UIButton()
        userProfilePic.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
        userProfilePic.setImage(UIImage(named: "profile_icon.jpg"), for: .normal)
        userProfilePic.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        userProfilePic.clipsToBounds = true
        userProfilePic.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        userProfilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        userProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = (userProfilePic.frame.size.width) / 2

      if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    userProfilePic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0).isActive = true
    userProfilePic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0).isActive = true
      }

      userProfilePic.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToSettings), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: userProfilePic)
```